# MongoDB eval function slow on 5m records update

Tags: mongodb, eval, batch-updates

To use the spatial functions from MongoDB I need to update the Dataset. 
When I run the following code over 20million documents it is still not finished after 8h.

Is there a faster way to do this?

```js
db.eval(function() { 
db.test.find({}).forEach(function(e) {
    e.geometry = {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [e.SA_X_COORD, e.SA_Y_COORD]}
    db.test.save(e);
});
},
{ nolock: true });
```

Comment: Not surprised, what do you think its doing? I have no idea why you are evaling that

Comment: Well, I know it's iterating through each document. Thats why I'm asking for a better solution to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was able to speed it up quite a bit by changing

```
db.test.save(e);
to 
db.test.update(e);
```